# form view and external IBindableTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview, ibindabletemplate

I would like to set the one template for edit/insert and view in my custom FormView control . But i got these odd exception

**`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table'.`**

```
public class CustomFormView : FormView
    {
        [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty), TemplateContainer(typeof(FormView), BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
        public IBindableTemplate FormTemplate { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
            if (FormTemplate != null)
            {
                if (CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
                {
                    FormTemplate.InstantiateIn(this);
                }
            }
            base.OnInit(e);
        }
    }
```

**edited :**

in the first step , I created the new user control and added a formview ("FV")

```
public partial class Form : UserControl
{
    private IBindableTemplate _template = null;

    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
    TemplateContainer(typeof(FormView), System.ComponentModel.BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
    public IBindableTemplate FormTemplate { set;get }

    protected void Page_Init()
    {
        if (FormTemplate != null)
        {
            FV.InsertItemTemplate = FV.EditItemTemplate = FormTemplate;
            if (!IsPostBack) FormTemplate.InstantiateIn(FV);
        }
    }
}
```

Now , I want to convert this user control to web control .

I would appreciate it if you could reply my question.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do??

Whatever it is you're trying to do, you're doing it wrong.

`TemplateContainer(typeof(FormView))` This is not possible.

You need to provide your own type there, inheriting from `IDataItemContainer`.

**Edit:**

I wouldn't recommend putting all this effort just because you want to have 1 template for edit and insert. Better put the same contents in both templates. Experience learns that over time you will want distinct functionallity for edit and insert.

Comment: dear Jeroen , thank you for your response , I've changed my post , would you please help me to find the solution , thank you.

Comment: Why do you want a template? Do you want to use 1 template for Edit and Insert?

Comment: exactly , I am not really interested in creation a unique template by property , is it possible to clone "insert template" , and set that for edit's template ?!or sth. like this ? thanks-